# Doctrine PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a schema using `vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` but getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table 'eventapp.event' doesn't exist in
>   C:\\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:105

I'm using MySQL and Doctrine ORM 2. The schema existed before with the same tables and I used `vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:drop --force` right before, which executed correctly, so it can't be a problem with the connection. `orm:schema-tool:update` gives me the same error.

I tried deleting the schema and creating it again with the same name, still getting the error. I have also checked the annotations for each entity class, they're all correct. Example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 **/
class Event
{
  ...
```

**My guess**: I have two entities with a Many-to-One association to `event` and I'm assuming the schema tool is looking for that table when creating the schema, and since it doesn't exist, I'm getting this error. The fact that I'm getting the error twice seems to support that, but I might be completely wrong. This is what the association looks like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $event;
```

with no corresponding entry in `event` since I only need it to be unidirectional.

*Edit*: Nope. Removed all associations from my entities. Still getting the exact same error message. I'm completely lost here.

How can I get Doctrine to correctly create the schema here? I haven't tried creating an empty `event` table, but that wouldn't be a desired solution anyway since I want it to be easily deployable with no further setup...

Answer (score 1):

...I figured out what the problem was, for anyone encountering the same error. In my `bootstrap.php`, I was retrieving data from the table using the Entity Manager (`$eventRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Event')` for example). Removing this code made the command execute correctly.